# How to remove wp customize sections in genesis

Tags: wordpress, genesis

Can one help me to remove the customizer section in genesis. i want to remove color section from the theme customizer in genesis.tried many code but now working. can anyone help me with code

```
 add_action( 'customize_register', 'wpse8170_customize_register' );
   function wpse8170_customize_register( WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize ) {
         $wp_customize->remove_section('id-of-section');

     }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble with this too, until I found this code. Just stick it in your functions.php

```
// Removing Genesis Sections from Customizer page
add_action( 'customize_register', 'gd_remove_customize_section', 20 );
function gd_remove_customize_section($wp_customize){
    $wp_customize->remove_section( 'genesis_layout');
    $wp_customize->remove_section( 'genesis_breadcrumbs');
    $wp_customize->remove_section( 'genesis_comments');
    $wp_customize->remove_section( 'genesis_archives');
}
```